# Send non-editable Array with JSON & Ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, send

Is it possible to send non-editable arrays?

What i'm trying to send is:

```
var items = [];
//console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
allitems = JSON.stringify(items);

[{
    "assetid": "7814010469",
    "classid": "1797256701",
    "instanceid": "0",
    "name_color": "D2D2D2",
    "icon_url": "-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFYznarJJjkQ6ovjw4SPlfP3auqEl2oBuJB1j--WoY322QziqkdpZGr3IteLMlhpw4RJCv8",
    "market_hash_name": "Gamma Case"
}]

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "jackpot/deposit",
    data: {
        myData: allitems
    },
    success: function(body) {
        toastr["info"]("Success! Our bots are generating your trade. Please wait...", "Inventory");
    },
});
```

But I want to make it not editable via the console.
And send it.

Comment: What do you mean by non-editable?

Comment: What is `allitems`? Your variable is `items`.

Comment: I mean i want my script to add 'items' to the array, but I don't want the user to edit or manipulate the array via the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to prevent the array from being changed. For example:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
Object.freeze(arr);
arr.push(4); // error
```

Comment: But the 'items' are being selected from an inventory. If I freeze it, the script can't add them to the array at all.

Comment: @MustafaKutlu Freeze the array after all manipulation is done but before it is sent.

Comment: The user can push several items into the array. If I freeze it after the items are pushed, they can stil edit before it is pushed. And freeze after 1 push is not an option because the array becomes locked. Im losing my mind..

Comment: @MustafaKutlu So you are worried about the user being able to access the variables from the console? Why not use local variables then?

Comment: Yes exactly. How should I use local variables?

Comment: @MustafaKutlu Check out W3Schools for that: [http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Basically, local variables are created when they are declared inside a function, and global variables are created when they are declared outside all functions.